# How to get list of models that are executes while loading list view in admin

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am writing custom list view in django admin (map showing places of addresses) that will be available like this:

[image: a list]

And i need to get a list of models that are also used to generate list in the bottom of screenshot.

I was looking for a right method in doc of ModelAdmin, but I didn't find anything interesting

```
class CompanyAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'get_first_image', 'get_city', 'get_street]
    search_fields = ['name', 'categories__name', 'trades__name', 'tax_id', 'www', 'email']
    list_filter = [('categories', CompanyCategoryTreeFilter), UserInStaffFilter]
    filter_vertical = ['categories', 'trades']
    inlines = [AttributeValueInline, CompanyPersonInline, NoteReadOnlyInline, NoteInline,
               NoteHiddenReadOnlyInline]
    resource_class = CompanyResource

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.person_responsible_fk:
            obj.person_responsible_fk = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    class Media:
        js = (
            'js/contacts.js',
        )

    change_list_template = 'admin/contacts/company/change_list.html'

admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

```
% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}


{% block object-tools-items %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'maps' %}">Mapa</a>
    </li>

{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
    {% leaflet_map "yourmap" callback="window.map_init_basic" %}
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function map_init_basic (map, options) {

        L.marker([10.10, 20.20]).addTo(map);
        L.marker([50.5, 30.5]).addTo(map);

    }
    </script>

    <style>

    .leaflet-container {  /* all maps */
        width:  600px;
        height: 400px;
    }

    #specialbigmap {
        height: 800px;
    }

    /* Resize the "display_raw" textbox */
    .django-leaflet-raw-textarea {
        width: 100%;
    }

    </style>

{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

I expect to get actual list of Companies that are used to load page with list, while it is loading, and display it in JS script

I found currently only method 'get_queryset' but i all the time gives mi Queryset of all companies, even if I use search field to find one instance - it gives me still all companies that are in DB

Comment: you haven't said what's the problem with your current code: what is it doing that you don't expect? what's the error?

Comment: @dirkgroten I don't get list of Companies in django that are used to load page with list, while it is loading. Actually I get nothing because I don't have any idea how to do this.

Comment: I don't understand "that are used to load page with list while it is loading". Your `CompanyAdmin` is listing all companies (name, get_first_image, etc..) right?

Comment: Yes, and I want to get this request and modify to send it also to a map